# Select rows where two specific columns are both non-null

Tags: python, pandas

I essentially want to do this

```
mrgd.query('security == security and comnam == comnam')
```

But this just false always.

Alternatively I was thinking maybe I could do

```
mrgd.eval('security == security') & mrgd.eval(comnam == comnam')
```

But this doesn't work.

```
mrgd['security'].notnull() == mrgd['comnam'].notnull()
```

I suppose I could do this

```
mrgd[['security','comnam']].notnull()
```

and then sum the two columns generated to get an integer (2 would mean it was successful) but what's the conventional way for doing this? I've found questions similar to this but not quite the same thing.

Comment: What do you mean by “null”? There are a few different ways of indicating a “null” value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can do like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [[None, None], 
     [3, None], 
     [None, 2], 
     [2, 3]], 
    columns=['security', 'comnam',],
)
df[df['security'].notnull() & df['comnam'].notnull()]
```

The result is:

```
  security  comnam
3   2.0 3.0
```

I have tried:

```
df.query('security == security and comnam == comnam')
```

And the result is the same.

Comment: You're right. I might have been a little brain dead yesterday. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The recommended way is using `isna`, `notna` vs `isnull`, `notnull`. On checking both columns, just chain additional `all` on `axis=1`

Check both columns are Non-`NaN`

```
mrgd[['security','comnam']].notna().all(1)
```

Check either columns are Non-`NaN`

```
mrgd[['security','comnam']].notna().any(1)
```

Comment: I really like the syntax on this one. Thank you for the answer!